# scrapyd error while deploying with scrapyd-client

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapyd

While executing the command:

```
scrapyd-deploy default
```

I'm runnning into an error saying:

```
File"/home/user/miniconda3/envs/quickcompany/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapyd_client/deploy.py", line 23, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.http import basic_auth_header
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.utils.http'
```

I have tried uninstalling and resinstalling the relevant libraries.
Also tried using both the github and packaged versions of scrapyd-client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering about the answer, there was a glitch in the library. I tried upgrading scrapyd client and it seemed to work fine from there on out

Answer (score 0):

Twisted versions before 18.9 used scrapy.utils.http (which is deprecated) if you want to use scrapyd-client change `from scrapy.utils.http import basic_auth_header` to `from w3lib.http import basic_auth_header` in the scrapyd-deplo.py file although I would recommend you not to use deprecated packages.

Answer (score 0):

Little Modification to LuisA310 solution, it should be `from w3lib.http import basic_auth_header` for `scrapyd-client==1.2.0a1`